# Are there any places to sleep in Helsinki Vantaa airport the night before an early flight?

Tags: airports, sleeping, helsinki, hel

I have an early morning flight out of Helsinki Vantaa airport and am thinking of spending the night there. Are there any places where I can get some sleep? I'm mainly looking for landside options since I will not be allowed airside before dropping my bag, but knowing about both can't hurt. I might even be willing to pay.

Comment: The Hilton is basically attached to the terminal, gets good reviews, and sometimes has some good rates when on sale, so you could always look at just booking a room there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a 'rest area' of sorts if you can get airside, according to [sleepinginairports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/helsinki.htm), and the airport is open 24 hours.  Nothing great though, unless you pay - there are hotels available.

> Rest Zone - The Kainuu Lounge is a space that is open to all
>   passengers who are looking to a quiet place to rest and relax between
>   flights. They don't offer much in terms of seating, but apparently
>   laying on the carpeted floor is comfortable. Location: Airside, Gate
>   31. Hours: open 24 hours.

There are some lounges, hotels, and 24 hour cafes, which if it were me, would be where I'd head - they often have comfy seats and don't care about overnight nappers, based on many experiences in other airports.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I had to stay landside since I had bags to check in. I managed to find a row of benches in front of my check-in desk and slept on these. Although the benches had no armrest, thus allowing me to lie down properly, they were made of metal and were padded by some feeble cushioning. Moreover the place can get quite noisy at various points during the night due to cleaning staff doing their jobs, and other miscellaneous machines buzzing about. All in all the place is not the best I've ever slept in, but I still managed to get some rest so I count it as a win.